# next.js program not running when i run yarn dev the below error showing

Tags: node.js, next.js, node-modules, nodes, yarn-lock.json

```
& : The term 'node.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\nayak\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.ps1:24 char:7
+     & "node$exe"  "$basedir/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js" $args
+       ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I install the node 64 bit this program is not running how can I solve this

Answer (score 0):

Can you please confirm if nodejs is install correctly in your windows or not ?

Run this in your windows terminal:

```
node -v
```